# Pandas dataframe update column for lowest x values in group?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have some race data in a csv file that looks like this:

[image]

My aim is to update the 'FAV' for each race in the table relative to the 'BSP' value - lowest BSP = 1, 2nd lowest = 2. (full data has 1k+ races)

Using a dataframe I found a solution with the following lines:

`df.loc[df.sort_values(['BSP'],ascending=True).groupby(['MENU_HINT','EVENT_DT']).head(2).index, ['FAV']] = 2`

to first number the lowest 2 'BSP' values each with a '2' in the 'FAV' column, then
`df.loc[df.sort_values(['TRAP'],ascending=True).groupby(['MENU_HINT','EVENT_DT']).BSP.idxmin(), ['FAV']] = 1`
to update the 'FAV' to 1 for the lowest 'BSP' value row (I sorted by trap to cover the instance where there are 2 with the same 'BSP' value - in this scenario lowest trap number takes priority)

I have limited experience with Pandas and dataframes so this was achieved through a lot of trial and error. I feel there is a more straight forward solution to achieve this but I am not sure what it would be.  Ideally if there is a simpler solution would it be possible to make it so I can change the top X number say to 3 so it numbers the lowest 3 prices 1,2 and 3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us calculate [`rank`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.rank.html)of BSP per group

```
df['FAV'] = df.groupby(['MENU_HINT','EVENT_DT'])['BSP'].rank(method='dense')
```

Comment: Wow thank you! That is so much simpler.  If I wanted to add the sort by trap before ranking would I just add `.sort_values('TRAP')` before groupby?

Comment: If you want to handle ties then probably its best to use `method='first'`: `df.sort_values(['BSP', 'TRAP']).groupby(['MENU_HINT','EVENT_DT'])['BSP'].rank(method='first')`